# Get only filename from S3 bucket in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I am trying to get files from S3 bucket and then downloading it on my local for the processing. I am able to do it using below code. But, there could be multiple files in the S3 bucket and I need only File Name.
The current code is also returning folder name with the file name. Is there a way to skip the folder and only get the file names ? For single file, I am manually passing name of the file but it won't be possible if I have multiple files.

**File location : s3bucket/4275/input/Test.csv**

```
import io.minio.*;
import io.minio.errors.*;
import io.minio.messages.Item;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

@Configuration
public class S3BucketConfig {
    @Value("${s3.bucket.accessKey}")
    private String s3BucketAccessKey;

    @Value("${s3.bucket.secretKey}")
    private String s3BucketSecretKey;

    @Value("${s3.bucket.endpoint}")
    private String s3BucketEndpoint;

    @Value("${s3.bucket.name}")
    private String s3BucketName;

    @Value("${dest.path.to.download}")
    private String destDownloadPath;

    private MinioClient minioClient;

    public void getS3BucketObject() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException, ServerException, InsufficientDataException, InternalException, InvalidResponseException,
            XmlParserException, ErrorResponseException {

        //creating minioClient to access S3 bucket
        minioClient =
                MinioClient.builder()
                        .endpoint(s3BucketEndpoint)
                        .credentials(s3BucketAccessKey, s3BucketSecretKey)
                        .build();

        //check for bucket existance
        boolean found =
                minioClient.bucketExists(BucketExistsArgs.builder().bucket(s3BucketName).build());
        if (!found) {
           System.out.println("Bucket doesn't exist ");
        } else {
            // check for .csv files in the bucket
            Iterable<Result<Item>> results =
                    minioClient.listObjects(ListObjectsArgs.builder().bucket(s3BucketName).prefix("4275/input/").build());
            for (Result<Item> result : results) {
                if (result.get().objectName().endsWith("csv")) {
                    //loop for file presence if it is not there every 3 minutes for 5-6hours
                            System.out.println(result.get().objectName()); <--- output :4275/input/Test.csv
                            S3BucketDownlodObjects(result.get().objectName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

        public void S3BucketDownlodObjects(String fileObject ){
            try {
                minioClient.downloadObject(
                        DownloadObjectArgs.builder()
                                .bucket(s3BucketName)
                                .object(fileObject)
                                .filename(data\\Test.csv") --> this will place file on my local with Test.csv name
                                .build());
            } catch (ErrorResponseException | InsufficientDataException | InternalException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidResponseException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | ServerException | XmlParserException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example of what you are trying to do? Are you simply saying that you wish to strip-off the path from the S3 Object Key (filename) to save it locally? Can't you just strip out the path from the string within your Java code?

Comment: Thanks ! I was thinking if there is something in the library to get the file name but I was able to achieve the file name by stripping off folder name in usual java way.

Comment: Since S3 does not have the concept of Folders, you need to know /construct or extract  the path  of the object and get the file name.  @Praveenks, please mark the appropriate answers